# Any Maestro ATM in the US?

Tags: usa, money, payment-cards

I just got some compensation for missed flight from the airline in Europe, and they gave it as Easy Cash maestro card. I live in the states and will not be back to Europe any time soon, so I wonder if it's possible to cash that card on the US. I can't find any ATMs online around New England area that accept maestro. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you actually try any ATM? I have a (Dutch) Maestro card, but never had any problems with (most) ATM's in the US. Usually there will be a Maestro logo on the machine, but if it isn't, it might still work. https://www.reference.com/business-finance/can-cirrus-atm-locations-fc618eea88d2b741 claims that *Most ATMs in the USA accept Cirrus, Maestro and Plus cards*

Comment: Marstro is issued by Mastercard so you can try an ATM which can cash a MasterCard.

Comment: Try the card anyway. Maestro ought to work at nearly any US ATM, at least if it is a bank's ATM. Your luck may vary with private ATMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an ATM accepts Mastercard, it will, at least in the US, also accept Maestro cards. I would assume that in realtiy, it means that any ATM should be good enough.

To be sure, you can use Mastercard's [online ATM locator](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/find-nearest-atm.html) to find an ATM near your location. Under the 'more options' tab, you can explicitely select that you only want to find ATMs accepting Maestro cards. **Edit:** At least here in Germany, the Maestro search filter does not seem to work as it should. The search tool can't find Maestro ATMs in any of the larger German cities, although in practice, all (or almost all) German ATMs will accept Maestro cards.

Comment: According to that locator tool, ATMs accepting International Maestro cards are rather thin on the ground in New England.  I tried searching for a few towns, and there are several sizeable New England towns (Providence, RI;  Amherst, MA;  Nashua, NH;  Portland, ME) where there are no results within 25 miles.  And there are only two results within 25 miles of Boston, a rather sizeable metro area.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You are right. Perhaps the Maestro 'filter' does not work as it should. Where I live in Germany, I can also not find any Maestro ATMs with the search tool, although all ATMs in Germany in reality will accept Maestro cards.

Comment: I can confirm that the Maestro card worked in a few random ATMs in the US (that didn't have Maestro logo, just Visa and Mastercard). So, it looks like it would work in any ATM that accepts Mastercard.
Moreover, I was able to pay with that card at a supermarket.